# How do I parse xml files which is located on FTP in iOS? Is it possible?

Tags: ios, xml, ftp

I want to **load product data from `xml` or read product data from xml files which are on ftp server** but it is asking for authentication again an again.How can I pass server username and password at once.I am creating an app in iOS.

Comment: Please show us what code you have so far and where it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try iOS components that handle FTP operations for you, like this one https://github.com/albertodebortoli/GoldRaccoon (Objective-C)

```
self.requestsManager = [[GRRequestsManager alloc] initWithHostname:<hostname>
                                                          user:<username>
                                                      password:<password>];
```

Comment: I fount that GoldRaccoon is the iOS component to connect to a FTP service and do the following:

    Download a file,
    Upload a file,
    Delete a file Create a directory,
    Delete a directory,
    List a directory.
But I would like to know how to read the xml files directly from ftp server.

Comment: To read XML files, first you need to connect to an FTP service. Then, you can download and handle files in code.